# Can't add data to sqlalchemy in flask form

Tags: python, forms, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a register system.
this is my model:

```
class Register(db.Model):
    __tablename__='Register'
    nickname=db.Column(db.String,primary_key=True)
    password_hash=db.Column(db.String(128))
```

this is my form:

```
class RegisterForm(FlaskForm): 
    nickname=StringField('insert nickname',validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=5,max=10,message='5-10')])
    password=PasswordField('password',validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit=SubmitField('Register')
```

this is my html:

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>{% block page_content %}Register page{% endblock %}
        <br>
        {%if msg%} {{msg}} {%else%} !{%endif%}
        </h1>
    
</div>
{{ wtf.quick_form(form)}}
{% endblock %}
```

my set up:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy,Integer,String
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import os 
#loginM=LoginManager()
app=Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)
basedir=os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =\
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'database.db')


app.config['SECRET_KEY']=b'f8117c34101d2ee17688292df39e0e47288f38b565ed66d8d3b930ad9596f6c2'

db=SQLAlchemy(app)
```

finially my view:

```
@app.route('/login/register',methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    #sqlalchemy session
    session1=Session()
    msg=''
    #local session
    Rform=RegisterForm()
    if Rform.validate_on_submit():
        name=Register.query.filter_by(nickname=Rform.nickname.data)
        if name:
            msg='username has been used'
        else:
            name=Rform.nickname.data
            password_hash=Rform.password.data
            session1.add(name)
            session1.add(password_hash)
            session1.commit()
            msg='register success'
        session['msg']=msg
        return redirect((url_for('register')))
    return render_template('register.html',form=Rform,msg=session.get('msg'))
```

But the app always return the page the shows 'username has been used', even though I never used that name before, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding first() to your name query call.

So it can be:

```py
        name=Register.query.filter_by(nickname=Rform.nickname.data).first()
```

This way name will be None if user the nickname does not exist thus `if name:` will pass if so.

Otherwise, it will go straight to the `else:` statement.

Based on what you have done above, you have just called the Query object which in this case will never be None.